# Tell Azure devops to use particular options when doing git merges

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge

I want my Azure devops repo to do all merges like this:

```
git merge branchname -s recursive -Xignore-all-space
```

Is there a setting somewhere for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is not a setting for this. Azure devops repo doesnot have this feature to run customized git commands currently.

As workaround you can clone your azure repo to your local machine, and run above command on the target branch, then push it to cloud azure repo branch.

You can also create a build pipeline to run above git command in a script task. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more information about run git commands in pipeline.  You can also check out the example in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60322953/git-periodically-replicate-a-repo-into-another-one-not-reachable-from-outside-t).

If you want to [submit a user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Click **suggest a feature** and choose **azure devops**) to Microsoft development team. Hope they will consider adding this feature in the future sprint.

Comment: Requested at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1069117/custom-git-merge-in-azure-devops.html